# Removing the selected contours from all contours?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have a list of contours(contours_list) which is np.shape(contours_list)= (5,519)
and size of contours (in contours_list) are different, for example :
index 0 1 2 3 4  size (8,1,2) (16,1,2) (3,1,2) (199,1,2) (9,1,2) respectively.

the objects in my image are filaments with different lengths. I want to remove for example the contours with :len(contours)>12 (which is the number of selected boundary points in filaments)
This is my code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(contours_list)
extract=np.array(())
selected_contours_list=[]
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(519):      
        if len(df.loc[i][j])>=12:            
            extract=np.array(df.loc[i][j])
            selected_contours_list.append(extract)
```

out_put:
np.shape(selected_contours_list) : (1345,) which satisfies the condition! but I think there is sth wrong!! I can not understand what happens? Where are my 5 lists? I want to have the np.shape(selected_contours_list)(5, output)

index: 0 1 2  and size: (27, 1, 2) (28, 1, 2) (15, 1, 2) respectively.